# How many times must I beat the mysterious monk in the inn at Dice Poker to get his relic?

Tags: the-witcher-2

In Flotsam's inn in Chapter 1, there's a monk in the basement of the inn who claims he has a mysterious relic that he can't use, and that only those blessed of good luck may have it. As a result, we have to play at Dice Poker. Unfortunately, my luck's not that great, so I tend to win only every other game, and it seems like you need a winning streak to get the award, since when I beat him he says that my luck's not quite good enough to obtain it yet.

[image: This guy here.]

How many times must I beat him to get the award? What is the award?

Comment: I beat him once and got it. Next time you have the game open, go the main menu and look under "extras". The mystic relic is actually a coupon for Good Old Games, to purchase (among other things) The Witcher 1.

Comment: PFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFT WANT

Comment: @Mana did it work?

Comment: @Raven Okay, I got it too; after winning three times in a row through save-loading. It mentioned that I beat him using two pairs...maybe that's the trigger? Or perhaps it's based on your net total earnings(including losses) from him. Only problem is that the only thing in the Extras menu for me is the Credits, nothing about a coupon.

Comment: @Mana - well, it's *some* option on the main menu. Let me find it on mine... Nope. Once you get it, it appears under the credits option.

Comment: @Raven That's distressing. I did it again and still no coupon.

Comment: You're just looking for a link called GOG, which, when clicked, will take you to the good old games website.

Comment: The trigger is winning with a certain combination of dice, probably the two pairs you mentioned. I read that somwhere, but I haven't played with the monk myself.

Comment: Yeah, the two pairs of dice is what does it. Furthermore, even though the award isn't showing up for me, I found the site by finding someone posting in a forum with this similar problem. I'd answer but am not going to for a bit since: 1. I dislike self-answering and 2. I'm not sure if it's a great idea to link to a website giving you discounts on games.

Answer (score 8):

It turns out that neither a sum of money nor a streak of victories is the trigger for earning his "relic"; instead, you must win against the monk in Dice Poker with a dice hand of two pairs. This requires a fair amount of luck, since the only hand two pairs beats is one pair or two pairs of a lower total sum. If you're worried about losing money, save/loading before playing him is effective.

The reward for this is a link in the Extras menu to a site which also acts as a link to a discount on 11 different Atari games, including Outcast, Master of Magic, Independence War 2, and Master of Orion 1+2. The site that this link went to is now defunct and redirects to a spam site, and I'm not sure if this option is available anymore in the game since the special offer has concluded.

Comment: Wrong again, I have won with every type of hand multiple times and still no go with the Relic. I have had multiple wins with two pairs, even rolled two pairs on first roll and didn't roll again the second time, won the hand, and no relic. Same with rolling all dice again on the second turn, not saving one of them the first hand, won, no Relic. So at this point it is all guessing.

Comment: @Nicknelson That's weird. Okay, thanks for the heads up; I'm gonna unaccept this.

Comment: @Mana You can't get this "relic" anymore, since the GOG promotion has ended.

Comment: @QAzer Good to know; thinking I should close this as too localized then.

Comment: I don't think it should be closed -- lots of people are still playing, still encountering the monk, and not knowing that his offer is no longer valid. The question is still valuable. Maybe we need to add an answer reflecting Krazer's comment.

Comment: Confirmed that winning with two pairs does not make a difference.